# i created app with java and oracle

Tags: installation, java

I created a system with java and oracle (as database).

I want to run the system on another PC, without having my source code, but oracle and java(JDK) already installed it, so i want an application that creates setup like a program.

Comment: What? Could you re-phrase into something meaningful perhaps? ;-)

Comment: dear i wont create setup for my program .

Comment: Maybe export your Database and write a little Java-Programm which imports the database on the target system.

Comment: I have to wonder if English is not your primary language since your question is very confusingly worded. If so, consider asking for help translating your question from a resource of yours that understands English well.

Comment: It appears to me like @user2251723 wants to package the project and create a portable package to run it on another computer.

Comment: so how can i created portable package ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question rightly, you have built a Java application with Oracle DB and you want to execute it on another computer. You can export your Java application as JAR (Java Archive) and execute it on another computer.

Comment: thanks , but i do not give the source code to another computer

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: no , textpad as editer

Comment: I suggest you to use Eclipse or any IDE to help you with this. But if you want to know creating JAR files here is the reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

After creating a .jar (say myjavaapp.jar) file you can use the following command to execute it:
    java -jar myjavaapp.jar

Comment: dear , i created the jar file for my application , but i tested it not worked ! . please help . thanks for help me ):

Comment: My dear friend it is really difficult to debug the code like this. I strongly suggest your to 1.Use Eclipse 2.write (or paste) your code in that after creating class 3. Right click on the project and click on Export 4. Select Java -> Runnable JAR file and click Next 5. Select a destination for JAR file and click Finish. 

Preferably write some log files to see what is happening when you execute your program on another computer.

Another reason why your application fails on another computer is Oracle might not be allowing remote database access/modification.

Comment: thanks very much dear friend , hhh my ques is closed instead of answer my question , so i hated this staff and administrator of this web page , but u so mercy .